# Path Error when using CV2 programm on another Laptop

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, pyqt5

I have a working .exe on my Laptop, which processes videos via CV2. When I open the exe on another Laptop the UI loads fine, but as soon as I choose a video I get the following Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv: :cvtColor'
```

After a quick Google search, I found out, that there must be a mistake in the video file path. But I didn't hardcode the file path instead I used `VideoFile = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video Files", "*.mp4 *.MOV"),('All', '*')])` (from tkinter). So there should not be a mistake in the file path (as I said the exe works fine on the Laptop I programmed it).
Update: I installed python on the second Laptop and the .py does everything smoothly, yet if I convert it to .exe I get the same Error as before. How does this make sense? (I used pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe)

```
class Thread(QThread):
    globals.global_vars()
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(globals.VideoFile)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, globals.start_frame)
        globals.frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

        while globals.Reset:
            try:
                cv2.waitKey(globals.Speed)
                _, frame = cap.read()

                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                lower_blue = np.array([globals.L_H, globals.L_S, globals.L_V])
                upper_blue = np.array([globals.U_H, globals.U_S, globals.U_V])
                mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
                res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
                blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(res, (15, 15), 0)
                blur = cv2.rectangle(blur, (globals.Left, globals.Upper), (globals.Right, globals.Under), (0, 0, 255), 2)

                [...]
                h, w, ch = blur.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToFormat = QImage(blur.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                convertToFormat = convertToFormat.rgbSwapped()
                p = convertToFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1300, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.initUI()

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def initUI(self):
        globals.global_vars()
        [...]
        #Label to display video in
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 130, 640, 480))
        [...]
    def clicked_menu(self, a):
        if a == 0:
            #get file path
            globals.VideoFile = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video Files", "*.mp4 *.MOV"),('All', '*')])
            th = Thread(self)
            th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
```

I used PyQt5 for my UI and tkinter only for the askyfilename part.

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you print `globals.VideoFile` before `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(globals.VideoFile)`, just to make sure that you are getting a valid path ?

Comment: I tested it and printed globals.VideoFile right after askopenfilename and got the right path.

Comment: Can you also try `os.path.exists()` for the filename ?

Comment: prints out "True"

Comment: I have found a [Github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11782#issuecomment-402618554), where the `cap` is not ready right after `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, globals.start_frame)`. I think you need to wait for sometime by polling until it returns `True`.

Comment: So to be 100% save, I deleted the `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, globals.start_frame)` line and it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you try with some other Video file(s) ?

Comment: Getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe your 2 laptops have different build options or different libraries only one of which supports this video codec. Try checking and comparing `cv2.getBuildInformation()`

Comment: Just checked  `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` on both laptops and got the identical output.

Comment: You should check the return code of `cap.read()`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `ret, frame = cap.read()`.  Proceed to handle the frame only when ret is true.

Comment: @acw1668 unfortunately did not work

Comment: so I tried it on a 3rd Laptop and it worked there. The only difference I see, is that both Laptops where it is working run on win10 and the other on win7.... can this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have tested it on several Pcs, I am sure that Windows 7 is the problem. Since it was only important to me to get the .exe running (I'll just use Win 10 from now on), my question doesn't need to be solved anymore.